# doxygen adding examples

Tags: python, jython, doxygen

I am trying to add examples to python code.
Where do I have to put the `@example filename`, so that it shows in the class/module/package help, at the moment I just get an example list but no links form the classdocs to the examples.

I tried putting the `@example` in the class doc (I use doxypy to allow tags in docstrings), after the class, and just below teh top comment in the file after the `@package`.

While this is  a pressing issue, there is another question, can I make doxygen simply parse all examples from the examplefolder and create auto links between the classes and the examples without adding tags?

I have the following structure: `projectcode/aTreeOfPackagesAndModules` and `examples/aTreeOfPackagesAndModules`. The trees have axactly the same layout and the example files for each package have the exact same path/filename except of `projectcode` / `examples` dirs beeing exchanged. can I get arround adding example tags?

Comment: Have you tried running doxygen on a simple example such as that presented in the [`\example`](http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/commands.html#cmdexample) command documentation? Looking at the generated documentation there is an `examples` page and a link in the class documentation to the relevant example. Also, while this may not be an option, but since you are working in Python have you looked at Sphinx? It allows you to write code examples [directly in a docstring](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/markup/code.html), which in my opinion is better than separating code and example code.

Comment: doxygen allows that too, and i am currently bound to doxygen. Sphinx for my next python project, I promist (doxygen is not exactly optimized for python, its not my first question or issue with doxygen and python)